# SQL subquery or JOIN on two tables, match to once-removed value

Tags: sql, join, mariadb, subquery

Consider these tables:

Based on `id`...

- Bill is John's boss
- Hank is Andy's and Alex' boss

**`writers`** :

| id | name | boss_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 2 |
| 2 | Bill | 2 |
| 3 | Andy | 4 |
| 4 | Hank | 4 |
| 5 | Alex | 4 |

The `writers` have `papers` they write...

**`papers`** :

| id | title | writer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Boston | 1 |
| 2 | Chicago | 4 |
| 3 | Cisco | 3 |
| 4 | Seattle | 2 |
| 5 | North | 5 |

I need an SQL query that will return the `papers.*` for every paper written by `writers` working for Hank (`id = 4` ==> `boss_id = 4`). That happens to include Hank himself because he is registered as his own boss, but that's not so important.

Desired output:

| id | title | writer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Chicago | 4 |
| 3 | Cisco | 3 |
| 5 | North | 5 |

What I have, that has no hope of working:

```sql
SELECT * FROM papers p WHERE ( writers w AS p.writer_id JOIN w.boss_id = 4 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on right track to solve the problem. Here I am sharing two approaches: one is by using sub query and the other is by joining both tables.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table writers( id int, name varchar(200), boss_id int);
  insert into writers values( 1,'John',2);
  insert into writers values( 2,'Bill',2);
  insert into writers values( 3,'Andy',4);
  insert into writers values( 4,'Hank',4);
  insert into writers values( 5,'Alex',4);
  
  create table papers ( id int, title varchar(200),writer_id int);

  insert into papers values( 1,'Boston',1);
  insert into papers values( 2,'Chicago',4);
  insert into papers values( 3,'Cisco' ,3);
  insert into papers values( 4,'Seattle',2);
  insert into papers values( 5,'North' ,5);
```

Query 1( using sub query):

```
 SELECT * FROM papers p WHERE writer_id in ( select id from writers where boss_id = 4 );
```

Output:

| id | title | writer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Chicago | 4 |
| 3 | Cisco | 3 |
| 5 | North | 5 |

Query 2 (using join):

```
  select p.* from papers p 
                  inner join writers w on p.writer_id=w.id
  where w.boss_id=4
```

Output:

| id | title | writer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Cisco | 3 |
| 2 | Chicago | 4 |
| 5 | North | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=56ea66693fb2cc568c96944baaf1d805)*

Comment: In your Query 2, I found that `papers p` can simply be `papers`. Should you edit or am I wrong?

Comment: `p` is just an alias you can use it for simplicity or surely you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You can join both tables together using the writers table primary key and papers table foreign key, then specify the boss_id in a where clause.

```
SElECT p.* 
FROM papers p
INNER JOIN writers w ON p.writer_id = w.id
WHERE w.boss_id = 4
```