# SQL subquery as part of LIKE search

Tags: sql, mariadb, subquery, sql-like

From [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72322693) we learned to use a subquery to find information once-removed.

**Subquery we learned** :

```sql
 SELECT * FROM papers WHERE writer_id IN ( SELECT id FROM writers WHERE boss_id = 4 );
```

Now, I need to search a table, both in column values that table, and in column values related by `id` on another table.

Here are the same tables, but `col` values contain more text for our "searching" reference...

**`writers`** :

| id | name | boss_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John Jonno | 2 |
| 2 | Bill Bosworth | 2 |
| 3 | Andy Seaside | 4 |
| 4 | Hank Little | 4 |
| 5 | Alex Crisp | 4 |

The `writers` have `papers` they write...

**`papers`** :

| id | title | writer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Boston | 1 |
| 2 | Chicago | 4 |
| 3 | Cisco | 3 |
| 4 | Seattle | 2 |
| 5 | North | 5 |

I can use this to search only the names on `writers`...

**Search only `writers.name`** : (Not what I want to do)

```sql
SELECT * FROM writers WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%is%');
```

**Output for above search** : (Not what I want to do)

| id | name | boss_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Alex Crisp | 4 |

I want to return `cols` from `writers` (not `papers`), but searching text both in `writers.name` and the `writers.id`-associated `papers.title`.

For example, if I searched "is", I would get both:

- **Alex Crisp** (for 'is' in the name 'Crisp')
- **Andy Seaside** (because Andy wrote a `paper` with 'is' in the title 'Cisco')

**Output for "is" search** :

| id | title | writer_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Chicago | 4 |
| 4 | Seattle | 2 |

Here's what I have that doesn't work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM papers WHERE LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER('%is%') OR writer_id ( writers=writer_id WHERE LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('%$is%') );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to express this criteria is by using a correlated query with `exists`:

```
select *
from writers w
where Lower(w.name) like '%is%'
  or exists (
    select * from papers p
    where p.writer_id = w.id and Lower(p.title) like '%is%'
  );
```

Note you don't need to use `lower` on the string you are providing, and you should only use `lower` if your collation truly is case-sensitive as using the function makes the search predicate unsargable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want `to return cols from writers (not papers)` you should select them first, and use stuff from papers in the criteria

```
select *
from writers w
where 
   w.name like '%is%'
   or 
   w.id in (select p.writer_id
            paper p
            where p.title like '%is%'
           )
```

You can add your LOWER functions (my sql environment is not case-sensitive, so I didn't need them)

Comment: That's really good to know that overusing LOWER can be a problem.